# why oracle allows only one LONG column per table?

Tags: database, oracle, blob

Could anybody tell why oracle allows only one "LONG" datatype column per table.

Comment: Don't use `LONG`. They are deprecated (and extremely limited). Use a `BLOB` column instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LONGs were stored inline with the table data, so Oracle probably limited it to one per table because of that (performance hit as you'd be scanning over a lot of blocks) whereas LOBs are stored inline for only the first few k then go into the LOB segment for the rest.

As LONGs are totally depreciated and a major pain in the butt to deal with, stay well away from them where possible.

Comment: thank you dazzal..! I know it is deprecated. But just to know the reason I asked it. Thanks any way.

Comment: no problem. i hoped it was just a question out of curiosity :) now all we have to hope for is that one day oracle will use CLOBs in the data dictionary instead of LONGs ;)