# ora-00907 where is the error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
create table salary_details 
(
emp_id number(2) , 
travel_allowance long(10000),
housing_allowance long (100000),
PF long(100000), 
account_no long(10000), 
Total_sal long(100000) 
);
```

been banging my head on this since an hour pls help

Comment: What do you expect `long(10000)` to represent?

Comment: this looks nothing like a create table statement -- what are you trying to do?

Comment: Creating a table to represent salary details of employees in an employee management database project

Comment: The valid data types are documented quite thoroughly [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483).

Comment: I love it.  Only 100 employee ids are in the table, but their salaries go up to 10^10,000 (too long to fit into a comment).

Comment: LONG is a deprecated string datatype (for storing large amounts of data)  and not the numeric datatype you might think it is because of `long` in Java or C#.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments about your code.

- Oracle handles numbers via the `number` type.  You can use other types, but you might as well stick with `number`.
- You can provide scale and precision for `number`.  For most monetary amounts, something like (12, 4) is sufficient.
- Salaries change over time, so I would expect a time component in the table.
- `number(2)` represents numbers from 0-99.  That doesn't seem like a very large range.

So, I might suggest:

```
create table salary_details (
    emp_id number , 
    travel_allowance number(12, 4),
    housing_allowance number(12, 4),
    PF number(12, 4),   -- if this is a monetary amount
    account_no number, 
    Total_sal number(12, 4)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues I think -

1. There is nothing called long(xxxx). The correct syntax should be column LONG.
2. An oracle table can have only 1 column as LONG type. Refer one of the earlier posts - [why oracle allows only one LONG column per table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582213/why-oracle-allows-only-one-long-column-per-table)

Comment: You shouldn't be using LONG columns in new tables anyway; and the OP almost certainly doesn't really want a string type at all.

Answer (score 1):

`long` is not an numeric Oracle data type. It's an (obsolete) type similar to `varchar`.

Maybe you can use one of the following:

- numeric(18,0),
- decimal(18,0),
- smallint,
- integer,
- real,
- float,
- binary_float,
- binary_double.

Answer (score 1):

Datatype LONG  , Maximum size: 2 GB - 1. Only one LONG column is allowed per table.
So u can use only one LONG column per table...
[Refer this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903)

Comment: You shouldn't be using LONG columns in new tables anyway; and the OP almost certainly doesn't really want a string type at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your data types make no sense. `Number(2)` is not appropriate for an employee ID - it's maximum value with no loss of integer precision is 99. And `LONG` is a character-based data type in Oracle which is not appropriate for numeric values. I would also choose a better name for the `PF` column as it's not obvious at all what that column represents.

Here's a proposal with more appropriate data types:

```
create table salary_details 
(
emp_id INTEGER , 
travel_allowance DECIMAL(10,2),
housing_allowance long DECIMAL(10,2),
PF DECIMAL(10,2),   
account_no INTEGER, 
Total_sal DECIMAL(10,2) 
);
```